# Getting the terms from "Beautiful Taxonomy Filters" Results ot Integrate into "Ajax Load More"

Tags: permalinks, filters, ajax, taxonomy, pagination

I’m trying to get BTF integrated with the Ajax Load More plugin and am having trouble on the filter results that are using two differen t taxonomies.

Basically I just need to know how to query/call both terms from both taxonomies.

Examples of results with two taxonomies:
https://development-client-server.com/lily/grant/grants/1999/grant-type/discretionary-grants/

Examples of results with one taxonomy: 
https://development-client-server.com/lily/grants/1997/

The shortcode syntax for taxonomy parameters in Ajax Load more is:

```
taxonomy="grant-year:grant-type" taxonomy_terms="'.$year.':'.$type.'" taxonomy_operator="IN:IN"
```

So I need to be able to get each taxonomy and term from the filter results.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured it out!

```
global $wp_query; echo $wp_query->query_vars['grant-type']
```